# Change error displayed when wrong ID type is used with standard controller in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, controller, standardsetcontroller

I have a VF page that uses standard controller account. I want to modify the error message that is displayed when I type the wrong id (invalid) in the URL to avoid getting a message like this: (I want to still display the VFPage but with a custom message, as my VFPage doesnt include header and sidebar )
[image]

I have an extension for that page, and within the constructor I have something like this

```
try{
    this.acctURL   = (Account)controller.getRecord();
}catch(system.DMLException e){
    displayIDError = true;
    errorMessage   = 'Salesforce cant find an account with an ID of: ' + acctIDPage + ' Please contact your Salesforce Administrator';
}
```

also it is necessary to do:

```
this.acctURL = (Account)controller.getRecord();
```

inside a try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any way of modifying this page as it's one of the standard error pages produced by the server. This error is generated before your code even gets a chance to run so there's nothing you can do to handle it.

The only thing you could do navigate to a different custom page first that uses a custom controller, that controller could then attempt to verify the ID and type in an init method, and then display an error if it fails or redirect to the existing page if successful.

The custom controller would look a little like this:

```
public class AccountIdChecker 
{        
    public PageReference Init()
    {
        String acctId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

        if(acctId == '')
        {   
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'No id specified!'));
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            Id realAcctId = acctId;
            if(Schema.Account.SObjectType != realAcctId.getSobjectType())
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Id specified is not an account id!'));
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Bad id specified!'));
            return null;
        }

        <<return reference to existing page here>>
    }
}
```

And the page would be something simple, like this:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountIdChecker" action="{!Init}">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
</apex:page>
```

In answer to the second part of your question, `(Account)controller.getRecord();` will always return an account record (using the account standard controller), it'll be a new record if no ID was specified in the URL, or an existin gone if a valid ID is passed in, so you shouldn't need a try/catch block.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I guess it is not necessary to do this.acctURL   = (Account)controller.getRecord(); inside a try right?

Comment: No, just added that after you accepted, missed it the first time around. Not sure what type `acctURL` is in your code, but it should be an Account SObject.

Comment: yeah, i had something like:public Account acctURL { get; set; }, i just didnt want to add all the code. Cool Thank you very much!!!